# Visual Code não mostra fechamento de tags HTML

Tags: visual-studio-code

Colegas.

Instalei recentemente o Visual Code. Estou gostando do programa, porém reparei que quando criamos arquivos em PHP, algumas funcionalidades parece não funcionar. Por ex.: No código HTML, quando seleciono 



 ele não mostra o fechamento dessa tag . Vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estranho, pois os fechamentos em PHP ele mostra ou quando a página é HTML ele também mostra. Teria alguma configuração específica?

Peço apenas para que me ajudem nesse programa, pois já usei o Netbeans, Eclipse, Atom e Brackets, e gostaria de dar uma chance para ele.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta baixar e instalar a extensão `highlight-matching-tag`.

Abra o painel de extensões do Visual Studio (Ctrl + Shift + X) e procure a extensão `highlight-matching-tag` na barra de busca e faça a instalação.

[image: Foto demonstrativa]

Comment: Legal o esforço, mas a resposta está muito vaga, coloque exemplos.. mostre como instalar.

Comment: Melhorei resposta ...

Comment: Desculpe a demora Bruno. Funcionou! Obrigado!